# jquery table sorting and css fix for IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, internet-explorer, css-tables

I'm attempting to make this page compatible with IE 8. The jquery right now allows for classes to be assigned on odds and evens, but doesn't seem to be working on IE 8.

Here is the site: http://www.videogameinfo.net/pokedex

and here is the jquery: http://www.videogameinfo.net/settings/jquery.tablesorter.js

the css does this in order to tile the backgrounds consistently.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #0E0439}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #272E81}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:nth-child()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) is a CSS3 selector and is not supported in IE8 and below.

To get the same effect, you will need to use some javascript/jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: when I use this method though, when the order changes, the backgrounds do not. any way I can fix it so that they update as well?

Comment: I would bind to the `sortStart` & `sortEnd` events. Then, when sorting starts, remove the applicable css classes from the rows, then once sorting has finished, re-apply them.